# SWIFT UISearchBar Text Aligned incorrectly from right to left

Tags: swift, swift3, uisearchbar, swift4, uisearchbardelegate

Im trying to set an left to right aligned searchbar text programmatically but it seems like it adds the text on the opposite direction (like english) and then there are no results from the search.
thanks for anyone helping.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to make it in such way?

```
 searchbar.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
```

Also make sure you are using right-to-left language for simulator/device keyboard layout when testing.

It's helpful to disable "Connect hardware keyboard" (Hardware -> Keyboard -> "Connect hardware keyboard" -> remove checkmark) when testing on Simulator, in order to see keyboard layout.

Comment: you can also add:
if let tfOfSearchBar = self.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField {
            tfOfSearchBar.textAlignment = .right
        }

Answer (score 2):

```
    var searchTextField: UITextField
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        searchTextField = searchController?.searchBar.searchTextField as! UITextField
    } else {
        searchTextField = searchController?.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
    }
    searchTextField.textAlignment = .right
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add search bar for right alignment like below-

```
    func addSearchController() {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        definesPresentationContext = true
        let searchTextField: UITextField = searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "_searchField") as! UITextField
        searchTextField.textAlignment = .right
}
```

Let me know if it solves your issue.

Comment: It is always nice to have a comment if you have downvoted.

Comment: After searching everywhere, this is the only answer which I found. Nowhere else there is answer on how to change text alignment inside the search bar.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using only **UISearchbar** you are change alignment by using below methods:

```
var searchTextField: UITextField
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
   searchTextField = searchBar.searchTextField as UITextField
} else {
    searchTextField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
}
    
searchTextField.textAlignment = .right
```